# Text alignment with C#

Tags: c#, text

I have a string of text with lines:

```
string s = "word longerword longestword evenlongerword aditionalword\n
longerword word evenlongerword longestword"
```

I want to align them like this (one word under another with 1 whitespace in between words):

```
s = "word       longerowrd longestword    evelongerword aditionalword
     longerword word       evenlongerword longestword"
```

---

**Further explanation:**
The text is as one continuous string with '\n'(newline) character breaking the text into lines. There are no words longer than 80 characters in this example (thus word splitting or '-' won't be needed). I want all words in the column aligned so that no word in next column starts in a whitespace position of the word before if that makes sense.

Optionally, there should be less than 80 characters in each row. How should I approach this?

Comment: What have you attempted so far?  Are the words already broken into lines, or is it a list of words only?

Comment: Best approach is to specify everything on paper and go from there. Is the 80 char length variable? What if one word is bigger than the size limit? Do you want to use `-` where do you cut word when to big? I usually ask student to do something similar and they start with a tile sheet and 3 colors pen. Do we need to keep the same order? Why are the space not omogenous in your result set? detail the exact process needed to go from your input to your expected output on paper.

Comment: _I want to align them_ Where? What is the output you target??

Comment: The text is as one continuous string with '\n' character breaking the text into lines. There are no words longer than 80 characters in this example (thus '-' won't be needed). I want all words in the column aligned so that no word in next column starts in a whitespace position of the word before if that makes sense.

Comment: Python one-liner: `'\n'.join(' '.join(l) for l in zip(*[[ ww+' '*(max(len(word) for word in col)-len(ww)) for ww in col] for col in zip(*[ss.split(' ') for ss in s.split('\n')]) ]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty, but this code will definitely output what you want:

```
string[] lines = "word longerword longestword evenlongerword aditionalword\nlongerword word evenlongerword longestword".Split('\n');
string result;
Dictionary<int, int> wordSize = new Dictionary<int, int>();

// Build word sizes first
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] words = line.Split(' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!wordSize.ContainsKey(i))
            wordSize.Add(i, 0);
        if (wordSize[i] < words[i].Length)
            wordSize[i] = words[i].Length;
    }
}

// Output results
result = string.Empty;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] words = line.Split(' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        result += words[i].PadRight(wordSize[i] + 1, ' ');
    result = result.TrimEnd();
    result += "\n";
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
word       longerword longestword    evenlongerword aditionalword
longerword word       evenlongerword longestword
```

**How it works**

First, the program determines how long each word is.  It does this by going through each line, and then each word in that line.

The resulting word length is stored in the dictionary `wordSize`, with key `0` indicating the first word, key `1` indicating the second word, and so on.  Of course, the value is only updated if it *exceeds* the length of the word from the previous line.

After this, it goes back through each line, and each word, and then adds the padded word to the output, plus 1 character for the extra space.

Comment: Did some adjustments to completely match my case and it works, nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "word longerword longestword evenlongerword aditionalword word longerword longestword evenlongerword aditionalword word longerword longestword evenlongerword aditionalword";
StringBuilder alignedString = new StringBuilder();
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (alignedString.Length + word.Length > 80)
        alignedString.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    alignedString.Append(word);
    alignedString.Append(" \t");
}
return alignedString.toString();
```